# How to change Text Value after presshed button, React native

Tags: react-native, text

I'm developing an app with react native, and now i should update a text of Text label after a button click. The problem is that I can't use state for do this, because I have a lot Text and more I don't know in first how many are these.
I've tried this piece of code:

```
_onPressAction = (txtItemValue)=> {
       console.log(txtItemValue);
       txtItemValue.props.children = "Hello";
}
```

but in this mode I can see all property of my Text but I can't able to change it's value.
There is a method for do this, without use the state?

Comment: Suggest read document carefully before start to code -- at least the fundamental ones. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  updateText = () => {
  this.setState({myText: 'My Changed Text'})
```

This can also be used if you want to change your text dynamically.